# C# Launcher based on WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient, launcher

I'm creating simple launcher for my other application and I need advise on logical part of the program. Launcher needs to check for connection, then check for file versions (from site), compare it with currently downloaded versions (if any) and if everything is alright, start the program, if not, update (download) files that differs from newest version. The files are:
`program.exe, config.cfg and mapFolder`. The `program.exe` and `mapFolder` must be updated, and `config.cfg` is only downloaded when there is no such file. Additionaly `mapFolder` is an folder which contains lots of random files (every new version can have totally different files in `mapFolder`).

For the file version I thought I would use simple DownloadString from my main site, which may contain something like `program:6.0,map:2.3`, so newest program ver is 6.0 and mapFolder is 2.3. Then I can use `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo` to get the version of current `program` (if any) and include a file "version" into `mapFolder` to read current version.

The problem is I dont know how to download whole folder using WebClient and what's the best way to do what I want to do. I've tried to download the `mapFolder` as zip and then automatically unpack it, but the launcher need to be coded in `.net 3.0`.

Here is my current code, that's just a prototype to get familiar with whole situation, dont base on it.
`

```
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string verifySite = "google.com/downloads/version";
    string downloadSite = "google.com/downloads/program.exe";
    Uri verifyUri, downloadUri = null;

    string userVer, currVer = "";
    string downloadPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string clientName = "program.exe";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(FileDownloaded);
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(FileDownloadProgress);
        chckAutorun.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.autorun;

        checkConnection();

        if(!checkVersion())
            downloadClient();
        else
        {
            pbDownload.Value = 100;
            btnPlay.Enabled = true;
            lblProgress.Text = "updated";

            if (chckAutorun.Checked)
                btnPlay.PerformClick();
        }
    }

    private bool checkConnection()
    {
        verifyUri = new Uri("http://" + verifySite);
        downloadUri = new Uri("http://" + downloadSite);
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(verifyUri);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            return true;
        }
        catch { }

        verifyUri = new Uri("https://" + verifySite);
        downloadUri = new Uri("https://" + downloadUri);
        req = WebRequest.Create(verifyUri);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            return true;
        }
        catch { }

        return false;
    }

    private void downloadClient()
    {
        try
        {
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(downloadUri, Path.Combine(downloadPath, clientName));
        }
        catch { }
    }

    private bool checkVersion()
    {
        lblProgress.Text = "checking for updates";
        try
        {
            currVer = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(downloadPath, clientName)).FileVersion;
        }
        catch {
            currVer = "";
        }

        try
        {
            userVer = wc.DownloadString(verifyUri);
        }
        catch {
            userVer = "";
        }

        return currVer == userVer && currVer != "";
    }

    private void FileDownloaded(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnPlay.Enabled = true;
        lblProgress.Text = "updated";

        if (chckAutorun.Checked)
            btnPlay.PerformClick();
    }

    private void FileDownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        long received = e.BytesReceived / 1000;
        long toReceive = e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1000;

        lblProgress.Text = string.Format("{0}KB {1}/ {2}KB", received, Repeat(" ", Math.Abs(-5 + Math.Min(5, received.ToString().Length))*2), toReceive);
        pbDownload.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPlay.Enabled = false;
       if(checkVersion())
       {
           lblProgress.Text = "Starting...";
           Process.Start(Path.Combine(downloadPath, clientName));
           this.Close();
       }
       else
       {
           downloadClient();
       }
    }

    public static string Repeat(string instr, int n)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(instr))
            return instr;

        var result = new StringBuilder(instr.Length * n);
        return result.Insert(0, instr, n).ToString();
    }

    private void chckAutorun_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.autorun = chckAutorun.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }`
```

Comment: Have you considered using Clickonce to update your programs and install them?

Comment: Don't download a folder, download only your installer. If you search NuGet for `autoupdate` you'll find many packages that provide this functionality, like NetSparkle. Updating is a job for the *installer*, not the update checking code in the application

Comment: BTW there is a reason there aren't any recent updates to autoupdate packages. Programmers prefer package managers like Chocolatey instead of creating their own installers

Comment: The problem is the versions may be updated separatly from each other, for example program may remain the same, but mapFolder will be updated

Comment: Different packages then, with different version numbers.

Comment: If your web server doesn't allow you to retrieve an index of a folder, you can add a standard file with the contents and version numbers to each folder, eg `contents.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve what I need by enabling `autoindex` on web server and download string of files in folder ending with .map .

```
string mapSite = wc.DownloadString(new Uri("http://" + mapsSite));
maps = Regex.Matches(mapSite, "<a href=\"(.*).map\">");
foreach (Match m in maps)
{
string mapName = m.Value.Remove(0, 9).Remove(m.Length - 11);
downloaded = false;
wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://" + mapsSite + mapName), Path.Combine(downloadPath, @"mapFolder/" + mapName));
while (!downloaded) { }
}
```